# Prevent execution of uploaded php files?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

In my project users are allowed to upload files of any type. I need to ensure security against execution of uploaded files that can parsed by php (*.php, *.html, etc.)

Is there a way to tell apache not to parse any files with php in web/uploads and simply display them as plain text? What are other options?

Comment: If you want to have them just display as a plain text file, why not just rename them to filename.txt when uploaded? Or if you're lookin' to preserve the original extension, filename.php.txt. That whay it won't be executed, will be treated as a text file.

Comment: This addes a little bit of overhead for a client, if he wants to download a file and execute it on his machine. Just imaging what it takes to do it on Windows, if you have your extensions hidden. =)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keep them all under the same folder and set this line in the directory's `.htaccess` file:

```
php_flag engine off
```

That will also take care of other exploits such as embedding PHP code in .gif files.

Comment: This works. However, if the file is *.php, browser attemps to download a file. How can I forse "Content-Type text/plain" header in this case?

Comment: @Dziamid: I haven't tried this myself, but I believe `AddType text/plain .php` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You want the Apache SetHandler directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#sethandler

This lets you force all files in a directory to be processed by a certain handler. So something along the lines of:

```
<Location /web/uploads>
SetHandler None
</Location>
```

should do what you want.

Comment: This works good. *.php files are displied with "Content-Type text/html" header. Can I achive the same with .htaccess?

Comment: I'm assuming you can do the same thing: the docs say it can be used within .htaccess files.

Comment: Indeed docs say it can be, but it has no effect in .htaccess context. I have AllowOverride set to All in virtual host.

Comment: Try doing `AllowOverride SetHandler`, and make sure your AllowOverride statement is in a `Directory` section specified by a path, NOT a `Location` section and NOT using a regular expression. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride for a list of the limitations.

Answer (score -1):

why not just rename the file extensions upon upload to `.phps`?

To clarify PHPS is the source code view of a PHP file:

To clarify:

`file.php` => `file.phps`

quick google example:

- http://filext.com/file-extension/PHPS

Comment: This is quite straightforward, but I would like to keep original names.

Comment: no no you misunderstand you CHANGE the extension, not the file name `file.php` becomes `file.phps` hardly a big change.

Comment: no, I understand. I would like users to download a file without needing to rename the extension to be able to execute it on their machines.