# How to check if uploaded file (or text via text box) contains PHP code?

Tags: php, security, file-upload, sanitization

I am unable to find a proper answer to this on stackoverflow.  But perhaps it is just me being silly.

I have a user form where the user can upload a text file.  We are doing the sensible things like saving outside htdocs and renaming the file - but how can I check if the uploaded file contains some, potentially harmful, PHP snippets?  Also there is a text box which is saved as a text file and we'd like to check if the user submitted php code in that too.

Is it as silly as checking for "`<?php`"  ?  Can this be re-written in some form of byte form which would render this check useless.

Note that the file may contain valid "<" and ">" characters as part of the input - and I do not want to escape these because then my data crunching application will not work on this sanitized form.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any need for you to do this: you just have to take care the input is never used in a context where PHP code could be executed.

If you're receiving **form data**, make sure you're not `eval()`ing the content at some point. Other than that, you should be okay.

If you're receiving **files**, make sure you're storing them in a location where they can't be executed by the PHP interpreter. See e.g. [Prevent execution of uploaded php files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885643/prevent-execution-of-uploaded-php-files) also make sure you are never `include()`ing user-uploaded files - if they're files you need to display at some point, use `file_get_contents()` (and don't forget sanitizing them for HTML output).

Comment: But if you had to test whether a file contains runnable PHP code, how would you do it?

Comment: @Maltese why do you need to test for that, what is your use case?

Answer (score -1):

Replace the point with underscore between file name and the extension to be sure.