# PHP,Linux,Apache: naming file based on user input

Tags: php, linux, apache, security, operating-system

whats up guys?
so my question is simple: my application receives the name of the file as a $_POST['fieldname'] from user and then create the file in a folder on server, or in another case using the $_POST['fieldname'] return the path of the file if file exists. so, is it safe?!
thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it depends on how well you set up the security around your filesystem access and how you serve the files. If you are only allowing them to send information to a particular folder and you're sanitizing the input, you could be fine. Here's [more info on basic filesystem security from php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.php). However you want to make sure they can't php code in files and execute them directly. A good bet there would be to [not allow any execution from that folder using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5885737/2280630).

However, as the top comment on that php.net link says, you should really consider not letting your users name files, and you should think about trying to store as much in a database as possible.